# Using add or push to add items to an array in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am getting the following error while push/add items to an array in groovy.

`$groovy main.groovy
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [LProgressNotes;.push() is applicable for argument types: (ProgressNotes) values: [ProgressNotes@d35dea7]
Possible solutions: sum(), plus(java.util.Collection), plus([Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.lang.Iterable)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [LProgressNotes;.push() is applicable for argument types: (ProgressNotes) values: [ProgressNotes@d35dea7]
Possible solutions: sum(), plus(java.util.Collection), plus([Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.lang.Object), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), plus(java.lang.Iterable)
    at main$_buildOutNotes_closure2.doCall(main.groovy:82)
    at main.buildOutNotes(main.groovy:75)
    at main$buildOutNotes.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at main.run(main.groovy:64)`

Here is the function:

```
def buildOutNotes(incomingNotes, systemNotes) {
    ProgressNotes[] outNotes = systemNotes;

    //iterate incoming chares
    incomingNotes.each { incoming -> 
        //split the note further 
        def iNote = splitIncoming(incoming);
        //check that the incoming note is in the system note
        def foundNotes = systemNotes.findAll { it.ProgressNote == iNote.ProgressNote }
        if(!foundNotes){
            //add the incoming note to the outNote 
            outNotes.push(iNote);
        }
    }
    return outNotes;
}
```

Here are the articles that  show push and add use

https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2015/01/groovy-goodness-pop-and-push-items-in.html

```
def list = ['Groovy', 'is', 'great!']
list.push('rocks!')
```

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html

```
def list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
emptyList.add(5)
```

I am building the example code on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_groovy_online.php.

You can view the example here
http://tpcg.io/NGw4szCv

Here is the full code as well:

```
//package com.javacodegeeks.groovy.date;
//import static java.util.Calendar.*;
//import groovy.json.*;
//import java.util.Properties;
//import java.util.List;

//progress notes object 
class ProgressNotes {
    def ActionDate
    String ActionBy
    String Status
    String ProgressNote

    ProgressNotes(inActionDate, inActionBy, inStatus, inNote){
        this.ActionDate = inActionDate
        this.ActionBy = inActionBy
        this.Status = inStatus
        this.ProgressNote  = inNote
    }
}

//delimiter
String delimiter = "@@";
//out notes
ProgressNotes[] outNotes;
//date patterns
def dateInSystemPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
def dateIncomingPattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm ";

/************** SAMPLE DATA START ****************/
//incoming  note string
String incomingNote  = "2019-12-15T01:29:44 User1: December 13 went to pickup the toilet at the wholesaler " + 
                       "then went to site then remove and replace the toilet then  found out that there is a " + 
                       "fruit inside the toilet then clean up the site and silicone around the toilet then " + 
                       "throw the old toilet at dumpster." + delimiter + 
                       "2019-12-13T10:43:05 User2: applied 3 bottles of urinal treatment.  let sit for an " + 
                       "hour. augered out  urinal main. draining excellent.  tried augering toilet. object stuck in " + 
                       "toilet. will not come out. Don will replace." + delimiter + 
                       "2019-12-13T09:18:51 user3: PO 508758 - unclog Washroom " + 
                       "Details: " + 
                       "Unclog toilet bowl and urinal in. Room 116.";

//in system notes
ProgressNotes[] systemNotes = [
    ["2012-01-26T14:52:50", "User1", "DISPATCHED", "reassign to Space Planning to confirm space availability"],
    ["2012-02-01T12:23:05", "User2", "DISPATCHED", "spoke to requestor and she has a few relocations and POD requirements."],
    ["2012-02-01T12:23:45", "User3", "DISPATCHED", "Contacted Customer for clarification spreadsheet is forthcoming for this request."],
    ["2012-02-03T18:45:00", "User1", "DISPATCHED", "Extending date to allow for clean-up of backlog."]
];

/************** SPLIT incomingNote ****************/
def incomingNotes = [];
if (incomingNote != ""){
    incomingNotes = incomingNote.split(delimiter);
}

/************** PICK NOTES ****************/
if (!incomingNotes){
    //No incoming notes push the system notes out
    outNotes = systemNotes;
}
else{
    //check and build the outnotes
    outNotes = buildOutNotes(incomingNotes, systemNotes);
}

println("OUTNOTES Length: " + outNotes.length)
println(" ");

/************** HELPER METHODS ****************/
def buildOutNotes(incomingNotes, systemNotes) {
    ProgressNotes[] outNotes = systemNotes;

    //iterate incoming chares
    incomingNotes.each { incoming -> 
        //split the note further 
        def iNote = splitIncoming(incoming);
        //check that the incoming note is in the system note
        def foundNotes = systemNotes.findAll { it.ProgressNote == iNote.ProgressNote }
        if(!foundNotes){
            //add the incoming note to the outNote 
            outNotes.push(iNote);
        }
    }
    return outNotes;
}

def splitIncoming(incoming){
    //date time characters
    int dateTimeChars = 20;

    def dateAndTimePart = incoming.substring(0,dateTimeChars).trim();
    String remainingNote = incoming.substring(dateTimeChars);
    String userPart = "";
    String notePart = "";
    def remainingNotes = remainingNote.split(":");
    if(remainingNotes){
        userPart = remainingNotes.getAt(0);
        notePart = incoming.substring(dateTimeChars+userPart.length()+1).trim();
    }

    //build the object 
    def outNote = new ProgressNotes(dateAndTimePart, userPart, "", notePart);
    return outNote;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in your code (`ProgressNotes[]`), not a list (`List<ProgressNotes>`). Any of the mentioned methods (`add` and `push`) does not exist for Java (and thus Groovy) arrays. An array is fixed size, so once initialized, you can't add any new elements to it - you can only replace existing elements. If you try to add a new element to the array, you will get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Just look at this simple example:

```groovy
String[] list = ["foo", "bar"]

assert list[0] == "foo"
assert list[1] == "bar"

try {
    list[2] = "new"
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    println "Caught!"
}

list[1] = "abc"

println list
```

Output:

```
Caught!
[foo, abc]
```

If you want to use `List.add()` or `List.push()` (or event groovier `leftShift` like `[] << "elem"`) you need to use a list instead of an array.  Arrays are a good choice if you know the size of the collection is fixed.

```
//out notes
List<ProgressNotes> outNotes;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, sample worked after changing to `List<ProgressNotes>`. With List<T> have to use the `.size()` to get the count. insystem notes changed as well `List<ProgressNotes> systemNotes = [    
    ["XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX"],
    ["XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX"],
    ["XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX"],
    ["XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX"]
] as ProgressNotes[];`. Sample updated: http://tpcg.io/NGw4szCv.

Comment: Worth noting that `push()` in Groovy 2.5+ [prepends](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8325) the item to the list rather than appends it.